# Why is my import showing as undefined when I render my component in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, storybook

I suspect I may have something wrong with the configuration of Storybook... or Webpack... because I am seeing that a shared component being imported into another is returning an error such as:

```js
VM293:90 Uncaught ReferenceError: _somefolder_myimport_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_35__ is not defined
```

I have thrown together [a CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tng7q?file=/src/js/components/donut/donut.js) that bares the code to the smallest example I can.

Can anyone see what's going wrong here?  My co-workers and I have put a good number of hours in trying to hunt this thing down. :/

Update: Apparently, the CodeSandbox link had timed out and I had the Start script incorrect.  This should be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be the interesting way to initialize Donut function.  `initComponentScript` is creating an inline script that is out of scope from webpack's module loader.  Webpack does this to avoid polluting the global namespace.
You should just be able to take the code you have as a template literal IIFE and execute it directly in the `initComponentScript` function.  What is the need to create a new script tag and append it?

Here is something that displays 'Hey There' https://codesandbox.io/s/includestorybook-forked-1yjcj?file=/src/js/components/donut/donut.stories.js

Comment: Ahh... because I was new to Storybook and following a pattern established by others on the team... :(  Thank you very much for finding this!